# undefined reference to _imp_* in MinWG

Tags: windows, mingw

I want to compile a simple test project for a library that makes use of a ftd2xx driver. I already compiled it successfully on linux and I'm trying to do the same on Windows. The main difference are some minor modification to the library.

The test file I want to compile is this:

```
//#include "HPX-linux.h"
#include "HPX-Windows.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int devs;
    getSerialNum(&devs);
    printf("%d\n\n", devs);
    simpleTest("./myTest/");
    return 0;
}
```

And the preprocessing directives of HPX-Windows.h are as follows:

```
#ifndef HPXLINUX_H
#define HPXLINUX_H

#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"
#include <pthread.h>

// typedefs
//typedef uint16_t DWORD;
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef uint8_t bool;
#endif

// static const defines
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#endif
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE -1
#define RETRIEDTOOMANY -10
#define LOSTHEADFRAME -11
#define GOTAV 2

#ifdef __unix__
#define PRELIB extern
#elif _WIN32
#ifdef ADD_EXPORTS
#define PRELIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PRELIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __unix__
#define CALL
#elif _WIN32
#define CALL __cdecl
#endif
```

About ftd2xx, I have 2 .h headers, a .lib and a .dll.

With the driver properly installed, I could compile the library on linux with:

```
gcc -o test test.c -Wall -Wextra -lHPX-linux -lftd2xx -lm
```

I'm using MinGW on Windows. The command I'm using is:

```
gcc test.c HPX-Windows.c -L -lftd2xx -g
```

And then I get a list of errors type "`undefined reference to _imp__*`", being * a function. I expected them to be the functions of ftd2xx.h, but it also happens to function declared in HPX-Windows.h, including getSerialNum and simpleTest. Why does it happen when I'm using a .c source file instead of a library?

Comment: Does it even find the lib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by symbols exported with `__declspec(dllimport)` in header files that can't be imported from a shared library (.DLL).

I would recommend creating a `libftd2xx.dll.a` file from the `ftd2xx.dll` file and linking with that (e.g. if the files are in the current directory using `-L. -lftd2xx.dll`).

Or you could probably just link with the `.dll` file by specifying it in the `gcc` command, something like this: `gcc -o test.exe test.c HPX-Windows.c ftd2xx.dll -g`).

If that doesn't work check `ftd2xx.h` to see where `__declspec(dllimport)` is imported and see if you can set a define that causes the header to not use `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)` and link with your lib file in case it's a static library (something like: `gcc --static -o test.exe test.c HPX-Windows.c -L. -lftd2xx -g`).

Comment: I finally managed to compile it successfully by writing gcc -o test.exe test.c HPX-Windows.dll ftd2xx.dll. I guess that if I want to make changes to the library, I will need to compile it again as a library and the recompile test.c.